# importar bbdd error ORA-00038

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Al intentar importar una base de datos mediante la sentencia:

`imp system/system@xe file=database.dmp log=importLog.log full=y;`

Me lanza un error:

> IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle

Leyendo por stack EN comentaban que podía ser por diferencias entre el lenguaje de la bbdd de exportada y la bbdd en la que intento importar.

Entonces he comprobado mediante:

`select * from   nls_database_parameters;`

Todos los parametros son iguales excepto:

```
Destino-> NLS_RDBMS_VERSION 11.2.0.2.0  - Origen de datos NLS_RDBMS_VERSION 11.2.0.3.0
```

Aclaraciones

La exportación la hacen mediante la versión de pago de Oracle 11g, yo utilizo la version Express Edition 11g.

Comment: Tristmente, con Oracle, a menudo los errores no son muy buenos. Es posible que el problema no tenga nada que ver con el character set. Unas preguntas: ¿Sabes cual fue el comando que se usó para crear el archivo `database.dmp`?  En particular, estoy curioso si es que se usó `exp` o `expdp`... porque si es `expdp`, entonces no puedes hacerle un import usando `imp`. Tendrías que usar `impdp`.

Comment: ¿Y el fichero de LOG que se genera (importLog.log) te dice algo mas? El IMP suele dar problemas de compatibilidad hacia atras....

Comment: @sstan Pues desconozco el comando, pero yo he utilizado `imp` y `impddp`

Comment: @luisgulo Pues me dice lo mismo que la consola.